# How to create this effect with lines in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects

I am trying to recreate this artwork in Photoshop.

[image]

I am not sure how to create the lines moving toward the tool nor how to create the lighter color around the tool. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in Illustrator with the blend tool. You just need a **starting curve** and an **end curve** and create all the lines in between with the blend tool. This can be done with lines or shapes.

> Create a blend with the Blend tool Select the Blend tool . Do one of
>   the following: To blend in sequential order with no rotation, click
>   anywhere on each object, but avoid anchor points.
>
> To blend to a specific anchor point on an object, click the anchor
>   point with the Blend tool. When the pointer is over an anchor point,
>   the pointer changes from a white square to transparent with a black
>   dot in its center.
>
> To blend open paths, select an endpoint on each path.
>
> When you are finished adding objects to the blend, click the Blend
>   tool again.

From [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6443a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6442a)

Tutorials [here](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/illustrators-blend-tool-a-comprehensive-guide--vector-551), and [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/3d/creating-perfect-blend-illustrator-2099152)

Answer (score 0):

The effect you see on that promotional piece is actually being created by a Brush, not actual vector lines.  There's a number of similar packs out there, but take a shot at searching for 'Grid Brush Pack', I believe we have something very similar on our machines here.